# DataContext naming Best Practices

Tags: linq-to-sql

Are there any? Do you give the DataContext the name of the Database you are getting data from or..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if there are any established "best practices". I just name it with something that makes sense to me and lets me know immediately what it is. For me, that's to name it after the database.

So with Northwind database I have NorthwindDataContext.